# Kafka mirror maker: Data in some topics are not replicated

Tags: apache-kafka, database-replication, high-availability, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Using mirror maker to replicate data across two geo -redundant sites.
I am not talking about internal topics.
But, data in some of the external topics that are designed to be replicated are not getting replicated fully.

Topic A has all 100K data rpelicated (and actively replicating).

Topic B has a huge gap of 30K records yet to be replicated.
All are from the same kafka and same mirrormaker.

Error for such topic/data is: failed due to unexpected error UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID.
Any idea?